# Existence of one to one function

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that there exists no one-to-one function $f : ℝ → ℝ $ with
> the property that for all $x ∈ ℝ$ such that $f(x²)-(f(x))² ≥ 1/4$

My approach

Suppose that there exists a one-to-one function $f : ℝ → ℝ$ such that for all $x ∈ ℝ$, $f(x²)-(f(x))² ≥ 1/4$.

First, note that if we substitute $x = 0$ into the inequality, we get:

$f(0) - (f(0))² ≥ 1/4$

Simplifying this inequality, we get:

$(f(0) - 1/2)² ≤ 0$

Since the square of a real number is always non-negative, the only way the above inequality can be satisfied is if $f(0) = 1/2$.

Now how to approach? please help...

Comment: Well, what happens if you consider $f(1)$?

Comment: Use `$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$` for $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Use `$\in$` for $\in$. Use `$x^2$` for $x^2$. Use `$\le$` for $\le$ and `$\ge$` for $\ge$. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\exists f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x^2)-(f(x))^2 \geq 1/4, \forall x$ such that f is one to one. Then $$f(0)-(f(0))^2 - 1/4 \geq 0 \therefore (f(0)-1/2)^2 \leq 0$$
$$f(1)-(f(1))^2-1/4 \geq 0 \therefore (f(1)-1/2)^2 \leq 0$$
Then $f(0)=f(1)=1/2$ but $0 \neq 1$. Therefore f is not one to one, so no such function can exist.